# Android: Showing thumbnail pictures in real size

Tags: android, thumbnails, image

In my activity I have two thumbnail pictures. I want to show the pictures in real size if I click on each thumbnail. Is it possible? If yes what is the procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some of the approaches you can try:

1. **ImageSwitcher** you can refer to code sample in you [API demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ImageSwitcher1.html):
2. Place your thumbnails in a GridView and pass the Drawable resource object key to another activity which shows the resources full screen. A bit of advanced stuff.

Hope this helps,
Cheers!!